# How to cleanly exit from a second level function using next in nodeJS express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below is my stylized code :

```js
let the_function = (req, res, next) => {
    Promise
        .map(promises_params, (x) => {
                return get_promise(x);
            }, {concurrency: 20}
        ).then((values) => {

        let reduceFunc = (acc, currV, currI) => {
            if (something_bad) {
                next(new Error("something bad happened");
                return;
            } else {
                return acc;    
            }
        };
        let result = values.reduce(reduceFunc,[]);
        res.send(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send(err);
    });
};
```

The idea is that I am running a bunch of promises then reducing the values I get to a single object which I then send back to the user.

When `something_bad` happens within the reduce function `reduceFunc`, I would like to get a proper error sent back to the user. But in my current setup, the node.js server fails and has to reboot after I get :

```
_http_outgoing.js:494
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

and the user gets an error which is not the one I would like her to see.

How to make sure the error I want the user to see is output cleanly without killing the server in the meantime ?

Comment: Why would you use `next` for the error in your reduce function, but not in the catch handler? It looks to me like you don't really want to use `next`, if that's the case you can simply `throw` the error instead and it will invoke the catch handler.

Comment: Indeed. It solved my issue. If you want to write it up as an answer I'll validate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are running into an error is because calling `next` does not stop the reduce function from executing. The reduce function continues to run and eventually `res.send(results)` is called. This becomes a problem because the next route handler is apparently also sending a response, but only one response can be sent for a request so you get an error.

The fact that you are not calling `next` in your catch handler indicates that you don't really want to use `next`. Since that is the case you can simply `throw` the error so that execution of the reduce function is haulted and the catch handler is invoked.

```
let the_function = (req, res, next) => {
    Promise
        .map(promises_params, (x) => {
                return get_promise(x);
            }, {concurrency: 20}
        ).then((values) => {

        let reduceFunc = (acc, currV, currI) => {
            if (something_bad) {
                throw new Error("something bad happened");
            } else {
                return acc;    
            }
        };
        let result = values.reduce(reduceFunc,[]);
        res.send(result);
    }).catch((err) => {
        res.send(err);
    });
};
```

Now a response is only sent once. It is sent if the reduce function completes without `something_bad` happening, or when an error occurs, but never both.